How to configure SSH with Google Authenticator MFA with specific IP policies - login without MFA for local newtork?
How to configure SSH with Google Authenticator MFA with specific IP policies:

I need to have access inside my local network (10.0.0.0/22) by just password-based login

> ssh user1@10.0.0.2
user1@10.0.0.2's password:
Last login: Wed Nov  6 02:18:27 2024 from 10.0.0.1
user1@server1:~$


but when I will try login to my SSH server from the Internet - I should login by password + MFA key.

> ssh -p 30022 user1@211.2.2.2
(user1@211.2.2.2) Password:
(user1@211.2.2.2) Verification code:
Last login: Wed Nov 6 02:18:27 2024 from 123.111.222.123
user1@server1:~$


You need two instances of sshd, one listening to internal IPs and one to external IPs.
So create two config files and create a second systemd service file. And there is also other steps like creating keys and more that should be done.

This can be done using pam_access.so.
These steps will configure MFA using Google Authenticator for the ubuntu user.  MFA will be bypassed for connections from localhost and 10.0.0.0/22.  They are based on a stock Ubuntu 22.04 server install.
Configure SSH.  KbdInteractiveAuthentication must be enabled for MFA prompts to work.
cat <<EOF > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/10-mfa.conf
PasswordAuthentication No
KbdInteractiveAuthentication Yes
EOF
systemctl restart ssh.service

Configure pam_access.  This will be used to bypass MFA for the specified networks.
cat <<EOF > /etc/security/mfa-access.conf
+:ALL:10.0.0.0/22
+:ALL:127.0.0.0/24
-:ALL:ALL
EOF

Install Google authenticator.
apt-get -y install libpam-google-authenticator qrencode

Configure Google Authenticator for the ubuntu user.  Add the information to your Google Authenticator app (or other TOTP app) using the QR code (or other output).
sudo -i -u ubuntu google-authenticator --time-based --no-confirm --no-rate-limit --step-size=30 --allow-reuse --window-size=3 --force

Configure PAM authentication for SSH to use Google Authenticator and pam_access.
cat <<EOF > /etc/pam.d/mfa-auth
@include common-auth
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/mfa-access.conf
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_google_authenticator.so echo_verification_code
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
EOF

sed -i s/common-auth/mfa-auth/ /etc/pam.d/sshd

see also
The Arch wiki page about Google Authenticator uses the same method in the section "2.1.1 Request OTP only when connecting from outside your local network".
